# Laravel getting tickets that user responded to

Tags: php, laravel

Hello im developing blog application and as a part of it im currently working on a ticket system where user creates a ticket and then admins are able to respond to that ticket in admin interface where they can see all tickets created. I want admins to see tickets they have already replied to so they can navigate trough the system easily but i had a problem - when i sent a collection of all tickets that admin has replied to it shows one ticket multiple times. Thats because i handle the system this way - I have messages table where message has id, isResponde, ticket_id, user_id, ... columns and tickets table where ticket has id, type, isOpened and user_id so one ticket owns messages which are linked to it trough ticket_id column. To get all tickets admin replied to i firstly get all messages he created which have isResponse = true so i only get messages from tickets he responded to

```
   $yourMessages = Message::all()->where('user_id','=',auth()->user()->id)->where('isResponse','=',true);
```

and then trough cycle i save those tickets to an array which have same id as ticket_id from messages. The cause of the problem was that if someone replied to one ticket multiple times i got that ticket saved to final array as many times as he replied. I got around that trough code bellow but now the problem is that if someone sent multiple messages in one ticket then only that ticket ends in the final array and all other are ignored eventho they have different id and are not the same one.

```
    $pom = 0;
    $yourTickets = [];
    foreach ($yourMessages as $message) {
        foreach ($yourTickets as $ticket){
            if ($ticket->id == $message->ticket_id){
                $pom++;
            }
        }

        if ($pom){
            continue;
        }

        $yourTickets = Ticket::all()->where('id','=', $message->ticket_id);

    }
```

If admin responded with only one message to one ticket, the final array gets all tickets which he responded to instead of the first one with multiple messages

Schema for messages table

```
Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->boolean('isSupportMessage')->default(false);
        $table->boolean('isResponse')->default(false);
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('ticket_id')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('chat_id')->nullable();
        $table->text('text');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('ticket_id')->references('id')->on('tickets');
        $table->foreign('chat_id')->references('id')->on('chats');
    });
```

and for tickets table

```
Schema::create('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->boolean('isOpened')->default(true);
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
```

Comment: It sounds to me like you should/could be doing all this as part of the query. If you show the schema for these tables and the query you currletly run, maybe we can help by doing all of this work in the query

Comment: I've added more info to the post. Hopefully its enought. If i forgot to add here anything just point it out please.

Answer (score 0):

Its a little hard to understand exactly your issue is but I believe your code can be simplified to the following:

```php
$messages =  Message::all()->where('user_id','=',auth()->user()->id)->where('isResponse','=',true);

$tickets = Ticket::whereIn('id', $messages->pluck('ticket_id'))->get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works! And i apologize if my english was the reason for bad understanding of my problem.